# rust unsafe half edge segfaulting

Tags: rust, linked-list, segmentation-fault, unsafe

I am trying to implement a half edge data structure with rust. Currently I am trying to implement splitting. To that effect I have this half edge struct:

```rust
pub struct HEdge<'a, V, E, F>
where
    V: Clone,
    E: Clone,
    F: Clone,
{
    pub(crate) id: GeomId,

    pub(crate) next_id: GeomId,
    pub(crate) prev_id: GeomId,
    pub(crate) pair_id: GeomId,

    pub(crate) vert_id: GeomId,

    pub(crate) face_id: GeomId,

    pub data: E,

    pub(crate) mesh: *mut HalfMesh<'a, V, E, F>,
}
```

Note the last field a pointer to the half edge mesh containing this edge.

I use this pointer to access the elements of the half edge, for example:

```rust
    pub fn prev_mut(&self) -> &mut HEdge<'a, V, E, F>
    {
        unsafe {
            debug_assert!(self.prev_id != ABSENT);
            debug_assert!(usize::from(self.prev_id) < (*self.mesh).hedges.len());

            &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[usize::from(self.prev_id)]
        }
    }
```

Note how the pointer is being dereferenced to access the previous half edge.

I am trying to split all edges in a mesh, so I am calling this once for every edge (every edge, not every half edge)

```rust
    pub fn split(&mut self) -> &mut Vert<'a, V, E, F>
    {
        unsafe {
            let v2_id = self.pair().prev().source().id;
            let v3_id = self.dest().id;
            let v4_id = self.prev().source().id;

            let vn_id = (*self.mesh).add_vert(self.source().data.clone());

            let e1_id = self.id;
            let e2_id = self.pair().id;
            let e3_id = self.next().id;
            let e4_id = self.prev().id;
            let e5_id = self.pair().next().id;
            let e6_id = self.pair().prev().id;

            let (e7_id, e8_id) =
                (*self.mesh).add_edge(vn_id, v2_id, self.data.clone(), self.data.clone());
            let (e9_id, e10_id) =
                (*self.mesh).add_edge(v4_id, vn_id, self.data.clone(), self.data.clone());
            println!("{}", (*self.mesh).hedges.len());
            let (e11_id, e12_id) =
                (*self.mesh).add_edge(v3_id, vn_id, self.data.clone(), self.data.clone());

            let f1_id = self.face_id;
            let f2_id = self.pair().face_id;
            let f3_id = (*self.mesh).add_face(e10_id, self.face().data.clone());
            let f4_id = (*self.mesh).add_face(e8_id, self.pair().face().data.clone());

            attach_face(
                &mut (*self.mesh).faces[f1_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e1_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e3_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e9_id.0 as usize],
            );

            attach_face(
                &mut (*self.mesh).faces[f2_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e2_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e7_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e6_id.0 as usize],
            );

            attach_face(
                &mut (*self.mesh).faces[f3_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e10_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e4_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e11_id.0 as usize],
            );

            attach_face(
                &mut (*self.mesh).faces[f4_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e8_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e12_id.0 as usize],
                &mut (*self.mesh).hedges[e5_id.0 as usize],
            );

            return &mut (*self.mesh).verts[vn_id.0 as usize];
        }
    }
```

Note the debug statement `println!("{}", (*self.mesh).hedges.len());`, gdb eventually tells me that a segfault gets triggered by that statement.

I don't understand how. The program is single threaded, the mesh itself is never moved or re-allocated (I tested it, the memory is always on the same memory location, never copied or cloned). Bu after maybe 10k iterations of splits I get a segfault at that line.

If I am not moving the data, how can that instruction segfault?

`self.mesh` should still point to the same data, and nothing has deleted that data (I checked), how does accessing that memory location suddenly become taboo?

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing what `HalfMesh` looks live. It could implement the `Deref` trait and implicitly perform another pointer dereference, however I would expect it to attribute that to the line where it performs the deref. Also what is `hedges`? If it is a `Vec` it should be able to access the length without any pointer lookups, but that may not be the case if it is a custom type.

Comment: You have a lot of unsafe code here. If you know this code will only ever be used in a single thread context, you can replace some of the `*mut T`s with `NonNull<T>` or `Option<NonNull<T>>` depending on what you expect the value to be. They will all appear the same in memory, but the compiler can help you by enforcing that the value is always valid and it is properly handled.

Comment: It's an LLVM optimization triggering UB on this code. Reallocating the arrays moves a heap pointer that rust tells LLVM is never moving.

Comment: In that case you will want to wrap the heap pointer in a cell such as an `UnsafeCell`. What makes `UnsafeCell` special is it tells the compiler that interior mutability can occur in an immutable context so it does not run into issues like what you described. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html